# Length of parametric curve in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus

I have to find the length of this parametric curve: $R(\theta)= \theta^4 $  with $0 < \theta < 1$

So, We have the formula: $ ds = \sqrt{r^2 + (\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2} d\theta $.

My question: As I have understood. I have to convert the $\theta$  into trig functions. How do I do that and proceed with my calculations?

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align}
ds &= \sqrt{r^2 + \left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2} d\theta \\
&= \sqrt{\theta^8 + 16\theta^6} \ d\theta \\
&= \theta^3 \sqrt{\theta^2 + 16} \ d\theta
\end{align}

Now, take $\theta = 4\tan\alpha$, and integrate.

Comment: Using $x=\sqrt{\theta^2+16}\implies xdx=\theta d\theta\implies\theta^3\sqrt{\theta^2+16}d\theta=(x^2-16)xdx$ is a bit easier.

Comment: @Ishan Deo Thank you. How did you get the $\theta = 4 \tan α $?

Comment: That was a substitution I was assuming in order to integrate.

Comment: Ok. So go integrate: $(4 tan α)^3 \sqrt{(4 tan α)^2 +16 }dα$?

Comment: You'll have an additional $\sec^2\alpha$ term as $d\theta = \sec^2\alpha \ d\alpha$

Comment: Shouldn't that be $4 \sec^2 α$? Since derivative of $4 \tan α$ is that? $(4\tan α)^3 \sqrt{(4\tan)^2 + 16 }(4 \sec^2 α) $ Is that correct?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes. There should be a factor of $4$.